# Precomposed icon for Flex (Flash Builder) Air to iPad app

Tags: ipad, apache-flex, air, flash-builder, flex4.5

When you create a HTML web app for the iPad you can opt to use a precomposed icon. This means that no gradient or styles will be added when the app is installed.

Using the Flex Air to iPad converter I can find no such option. The icon I use is automatically given a gradient overlay.

How do I tell Flex to use a precomposed icon?

thanks,
Chris